# Copy files in parallel by reading what files to copy from few other files

Tags: bash, linux, shell

I am working on a little complicated shell script for the first time and this is what it should do:

- During startup, it figures out what is my `clientid` by looking at `host-mapping.txt` file. If I cannot find `clientid` for my hostname then I need to exit from the shell script with a non-zero status code and log error message.
- Now once I have a valid `clientid`, I will extract primary files from the `primary-mappings.txt` file and secondary files from the `secondary-mappings.txt` file for that valid `clientid`. If for whatever reason, I cannot find either primary or secondary files for that `clientid` from that file, then I will exit from the shell script and log an error message.
- Now once I have valid primary and secondary files for that `clientid` then I will start copying those files in parallel using `gnu-parallel` from `local_server`. All primary files will go to `primary` folder and all secondary files will go to `secondary` folder. If files are not there in `hold1` folder on remote servers then it should be there in the `hold2` folder.
- Now once all the files are copied, I will verify at the end to make sure all the primary and secondary files are present for that `clientid` in those two folders, but if for whatever reason I cannot find those files, then I want to exit from the shell script with a message that tells me what files are missing.

My script does the job but I would like to see if there is any better or efficient way to do these things since this is my first time writing a little complicated script so I wanted to check this out. As of now, I don't have a mechanism to exit out of the shell script if I cannot find `primary` or `secondary` files for that `clientid`. I also don't have a mechanism to exit out of the shell script if during the verification phase some files are missing.

```
#!/bin/bash
path=/home/goldy/scripts
mapfiles=(primary-mappings.txt secondary-mappings.txt)
hostfile=host-mapping.txt
machines=(machine1769.abc.host.com proctek5461.def.host.com letyrs87541.pqr.host.com)
# folders on local box where to copy files
primary=/data01/primary
secondary=/data02/secondary
# folders on remote servers from where to copy files
export hold1=/data/snapshot/$1
export hold2=/data/snapshot/$2

date1=$(date +"%s")
# this will tell me what's my clientid given my current hostname
getProperty () {
   prop_value=$(hostname -f)
   prop_key=`cat $path/$hostfile | grep "$prop_value" | cut -d'=' -f1`
   echo $(echo $prop_key | tr -dc '0-9')
}
# if I can't find clientid for my hostname, then I will log a message 
# and exit out of shell script with non zero status code
clientid=$(getProperty)
[ -z "$clientid" ] && { echo "cannot find clientid for $(hostname -f)"; exit 1; }

# now once I have valid clientid, then I will get primary and secondary mapping
# from the "host-mapping.txt" file
declare -a arr
mappingsByClientID () {
  id=$1 # 1 to 5
  file=$path/${mapfiles[$2]} # 0 to 1
  arr=($(sed -r "s/.*\b${id}=\[([^]\]+).*/\1/; s/,/ /g" $file))
  echo "${arr[@]}"
}

# assign output of function to an array
pri=($(mappingsByClientID $clientid 0))
snd=($(mappingsByClientID $clientid 1))

echo "primary files: ${pri[@]}"
echo "secondary files: ${snd[@]}"

# figure out which machine you want to use to start copying files from
case $(hostname -f) in
    *abc.host.com)
        local_server=("${machines[0]}")
        ;;
    *def.host.com)
        local_server=("${machines[1]}")
        ;;
    *pqr.host.com)
        local_server=("${machines[2]}")
        ;;
    *) echo "unknown host: $(hostname -f), exiting." && exit 1 ;;
    # ?
esac
export local="$local_server"

# deleting files before we start copying
find "$primary" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rm -fv {} \;
find "$secondary" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rm -fv {} \;

do_copy() {
  el=$1
  primsec=$2
  (scp -C -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no goldy@"$local":"$hold1"/hello_monthly_"$el"_999_1.data "$primsec"/. > /dev/null 2>&1) || (scp -C -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no goldy@"$local":"$hold2"/hello_monthly_"$el"_999_1.data "$primsec"/. > /dev/null 2>&1)
}
export -f do_copy
# copy files in parallel
parallel -j "$3" do_copy {} $primary ::: ${pri[@]} &
parallel -j "$3" do_copy {} $secondary ::: ${snd[@]} &
wait
echo "all files copied"

# this is for verification to see all files got copied or not
# in primary and secondary folder
set -- "$primary" "$secondary"
typeset -n array
for array in pri snd; do
    for num in "${array[@]}"; do
        name="hello_monthly_${num}_999_1.data"
        if [ ! -f "$1/$name" ]; then
            { echo "$name" not found in "$1" >&2 && exit 1; }
        fi
    done
    shift
done

date2=$(date +"%s")
diff=$(($date2-$date1))
echo "Total Time Taken - $(($diff / 3600)) hours and $(((diff/60) % 60)) minutes and $(($diff % 60)) seconds elapsed."
```

Here is my `host-mapping.txt` file that will have lot more entries. Here, value is a valid hostname and key will be a string "k" followed by some number and that number should be there in the mapping files.

```
k1=machineA.abc.com
k2=machineB.abc.com
k3=machineC.def.com
k4=machineD.pqr.com
k5=machineO.abc.com
```

And here is my sample mapping files:

**primary_mappings.txt**

```
{1=[343, 0, 686, 1372, 882, 196], 2=[687, 1, 1373, 883, 197, 736, 1030, 1569], 3=[1374, 2, 884, 737, 198, 1570], 4=[1375, 1032, 1424, 3, 885, 1228], 5=[1033, 1425, 4, 200, 886]}
```

**secondary_mappings.txt**

```
{1=[1152, 816, 1488, 336, 1008], 2=[1153, 0, 817, 337, 1489, 1009, 1297], 3=[1, 1154, 1490, 338], 4=[1155, 2, 339, 1491, 819, 1299, 1635], 5=[820, 1492, 340, 3, 1156]}
```

For example: `clientid` 1 has `343, 0, 686, 1372, 882, 196` primary files and `1152, 816, 1488, 336, 1008` secondary files, similarly for other `clientids` as well.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a useless use of `cat`:

```
prop_key=`cat $path/$hostfile | grep "$prop_value" | cut -d'=' -f1`
```

That could easily be

```
prop_key=$(grep -e "$prop_value" -- "$path/$hostfile" | cut -d= -f1)
```

(I've fixed your quoting there, too)

---

Send error messages to the standard error stream, not standard output:

```
[ -z "$clientid" ] && { echo "cannot find clientid for $(hostname -f)" >&2; exit 1; }
```

I added **`>&2`** there - it's worth making this into a function:

```
die() {
    echo "$@" >&2
    exit 1
}
```

You could insert `logger -t "$0" "$*"` in there if you wanted, for example.

---

This long line is hard to follow:

```
(scp -C -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no goldy@"$local":"$hold1"/hello_monthly_"$el"_999_1.data "$primsec"/. > /dev/null 2>&1) || (scp -C -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no goldy@"$local":"$hold2"/hello_monthly_"$el"_999_1.data "$primsec"/. > /dev/null 2>&1)
```

I'm not sure why it needs to be in a sub-shell, but assuming that's necessary, we can redirect the stdout and stderr of the entire sub-shell, which will shorten command.  It might be worth identifying what changes between the two invocations with a simple `for` loop:

```
scp_opts=(C -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no)

(for hold in "$hold1" "$hold2"
 do scp "${scp_opts[@]}" \
        "goldy@$local:$hold/hello_monthly_${1}_999_1.data" "$2/." \
    && break
 done) >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I've just used `$1` and `$2` directly - but if you want to give them names, I recommend declaring them both as `local`:

```
local el primsec
```

---

For the final formatting of seconds into hours, minutes and seconds, you can use `date` again (as you seem to be assuming GNU date), if the duration will be less than 24 hours:

```
date -d @$diff '+Total Time Taken - %-H hours and %-M minutes and %-S seconds elapsed.'
```

That still suffers from the "1 seconds" problem.  You might prefer a simple numeric form:

```
date -d @$diff '+Total Time Taken - %T'
```

Comment: If you're just `grep`ing a file why use redirection?

Comment: Thanks @chicks - I did mean to let `grep` open its own file.  I've edited accordingly.

Comment: I recommend `grep -e "$prop_value" -- "$path/$hostfile"` just in case `$prop_value` or `$path` starts with a hyphen.

Answer (score 4):

## good

- decent use of comments
- using shell functions
- good indentation
- nice output to keep the user informed
- decent variable names
- not too complicated for a shell script.  And the complexity is reasonably well compartmentalized.

## quick hints

- use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to get helpful suggestions.  In your case it is mostly just suggesting to use quotes in a few more places and skip the ``` `` ``` (backticks) form of command substitution.  Since you're already using the more modern `$()` form of command substitution that will help make the code more consistent.
- line comments usually look better with a blank line above them.  Also, it'd be nice to comment the initial lines 2-11 as "defaults" or something.
- usually shell functions are grouped together near the top of the script right after the variable assignments.  If you want they could be in a separate file that gets `source`d.
- since you only call `getProperty` once to get the `clientid` why not include the error checking portion of things inside the function?

## better output and logging

You mention wanting to log error messages, but I don't see anything that write outs to a log.  This is easy enough to do with something like:

```
LOGFILE=/tmp/myscript.log

myerror() {
    local msg="$1"
    echo "$(date) $msg" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "$msg"         >  &2       # stderr
    exit 1
}

# sometime later...
myerror "something weird happened"
```

So, this will take your error message, display it to the user, and append it to a logfile, before exiting.  You could easily extend this to include the PID (`$$`).  If you like having the date/time in your output you could also create a `date_echo` or something that takes your message and puts the date on front of it.

```
date_echo() {
    local msg="$1"
    # echo "$(date) $msg" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "$(date): $msg"
}
```

Comment: I agree `local` would be an improvement so I changed that.  I'm working on the `stderr` suggestion.